# freeze when when playing video on chrome for android

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, video

I'm using chrome for android to play video, but when I click a button which trigger video.play(), it freeze and log output below repeatedly for about 1 minute. The video is not played.

```
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=9
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=5
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=5
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=1
I/amffmpeg( 1249): [tcp @ 0x400d1f50] ff_network_wait_fd return error -11,errmsg:Operation now in progress
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=1
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=9
I/amffmpeg( 1249): [tcp @ 0x400d1e90] ff_network_wait_fd return error -11,errmsg:Operation now in progress
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=9
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=5
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=5
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=1
I/amffmpeg( 1249): [tcp @ 0x400d1f50] ff_network_wait_fd return error -11,errmsg:Operation now in progress
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=1
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=9
I/amffmpeg( 1249): [tcp @ 0x400d1e90] ff_network_wait_fd return error -11,errmsg:Operation now in progress
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=9
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=5
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=5
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=1
I/amffmpeg( 1249): [tcp @ 0x400d1f50] ff_network_wait_fd return error -11,errmsg:Operation now in progress
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=1
I/amffmpeg( 1249): ff_network_wait_fd,retry=9
I/amffmpeg( 1249): [tcp @ 0x400d1e90] ff_network_wait_fd return error -11,errmsg:Operation now in progress
```

Comment: do you have a link to the video so we can test? my guess would be a network/connection issue. does other video play okay (and can you play the video in Chrome on a PC)?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with offbeatmammal, all data leads to some network issue.

Maybe you can try changing the network type, and see if other browsers will have the same issue with that video.